# ERROR HttpErrorResponse ,net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, angular, nodemailer

I am working on my first application in Angular. I want to send emails from a contact form, but I have an error that I don't understand its origin.

**server.js**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const http       = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express    = require("express");
const path       = require("path");
const api = require("./server/routes/api");
// create a new Express application instance 
const app = express();
console.log( "dans server.js");
app.use(cors({origin:"*" })) ;
app.use(express.static('public')); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
console.log( "dans server.js");
//start application server on port 3000
server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.info('Server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log("The server started on port 3000");
});
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
res.send("");
});
app.post("/sendemail", (req, res) => {
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'gmail',
auth: {
user: 'emailsender@gmail.com',
pass: '*******'
}
});

var mailOptions = {
from: 'emailsender@gmail.com',
to: 'reciever@gmail.com',
subject: "hi with angular",
text: " hello great i sent u an email!"
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
if (error) console.log(error);
else console.log("Message sent successfully: " + info.response);
});
});
```

the content of the file routes.js:
`router.post('/sendmail', actions.sendmail);`

code of sending mail in

**contactform.ts:**

```
mysubmit(fo)
{console.log("submit");

this._MessageService.sendMessage (this.user) .subscribe (() => { 
console.log(" service called submit");
console.log ("Contact form", "Message sent successfully", "success");
 }}
```

**messageservice.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable () 
export class MessageService { 
constructor (private _http: HttpClient) {} 
sendMessage (body) { 
return this._http.post ('http://localhost:3000/sendmail', body); 
}}

package.json:
{
"name": "perfect",
"version": "0.0.0",
"main": "Server.js",
etc....
}
```

**Error message:**

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown
>   Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
>   OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/sendmail net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[may be the picture explains more the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBHSA.png)

thank you in advance!!

Comment: Sounds like it may be a CORS related issue. Have you researched that? Also `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is often related to firewall settings. Are you running everything locally?

Comment: Yes possible cause of CORS issue or proxy is blocked. You can check for bypassing proxy

Comment: I added a file called proxy-config.json
`{"/api/*":{
"target":"http://localhost:3000",
"secure": false,
"logLevel":"debug"

}
    
}`
And added it to the start section in the package.json file ...but it doesn't work yet....